# What meta tag should I use to indicate the website (not content) author?

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags

**The issue:**

In HTML you can use `author` meta tag (or the *DC creator*) to indicate that someone is the author of the information (i.e. content). However, I want to be able to sign myself as a web application developer in meta tags.

Most people are (in my opinion) **misusing** the `author` meta tag for the web application developer signature. For example when you develop blogging application, the author should be the article writer, not the application developer. But the name of the application developer is still useful meta information.

I think that the *commonly used* set of meta tags is incomplete, because it does not offer a meta tag for this kind of information. Am I right, or did I miss something? What would you suggest?

---

**Additional thoughts:**

Meta tags in digital publishing are closely following meta model used in paper publishing and libraries. The set of [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/dces/) elements might be good example for that. If we use this analogy, then **publisher** might be what I am looking for. Still, I feel that it is not. Publisher might be someone else than the web developer. Can you find better analogy with the *paper world*?

Comment: Thank you Jukka and Rich for pointing me towards the right direction and useful resources.

My biggest issue was the difference between a **content author** and a **website developer**. Seems that there is really no simple answer how these two different subjects should be expressed if they are companies (not humans :)). For now the best solution seems to be: _expressing web developer as simple `author` meta-tag_ and _expressing content author as `DC.creator` meta-tag_.

In other words: use the plain HTML meta-tags for the website itself and Dublin Core for the content.

Comment: I think this question is now more appropriate than ever. Google is pushing hard to get author recognised as being the person who wrote the content on the page. Its also building up the importance of the 'Publisher' tag too. However it seems that Googles interpretation of that is for the actual company that owns the website. So Im a little frustrated that there isnt a formal tag for actual creators of the website.

Comment: i simply add my calling card/ name to the keywords meta tag and an additional developer meta `<meta name="developer" content="bobbyaxe">` which does absolutely nothing :) as it is not a standard nor do search engines care for it. but may become a thing someday...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Guess it's the typesetter!

I use three things:

1. [a humans.txt file](http://humanstxt.org/)
2. If the site gives permission, a link in the footer to my site "Web design by …"
3. A `x-author: My Business Name` header sent with the php.

The last one is a little pointless, but it's more there so a future developer who takes over might be able to have a clue who I am!

Comment: _Typesetter_ is nice analogy. Thank you for the _humans.txt_ link. Its nice initiative and I like that [Google has its own](http://www.google.com/humans.txt) (even thou its not in the correct format) :).

Answer (score 3):

You can use pretty much any `name` attribute in a `meta` tag, just as you like. The tags will be ignored anyway, except perhaps when the document is processed by some site-specific indexing robot or something similar. It’s largely comparable to a comment.

You can check http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-meta-element.html#the-meta-element (and http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions which is referred to by it) and then decide to use `author` or `dcterms.contributor`. Or maybe invent your own, like `programmer`.

Calling an application developer an author is quite OK. “Author” does not mean just a creator of a literary work.

Comment: Calling web developer as _author_ is incorrect for me. If you have web site with scientific articles you should use author (preferably the Dublin Core variant) for the article author (researcher).

I also know that meta-tags are more of a free form. This is general problem of any metadata. But that does not mean meta tags should be free-text.

Comment: By the way creating my own meta tag is option I am considering. But I wanted to know if someone else ended with the same conclusion. Thanks for the link to the list of meta tag proposals.

Comment: Found the [same discussion](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Talk:MetaExtensions#Re:_Proposed_.27creator.27_MetaExtension) behind proposed `creator` tag, which is suggesting that `author` should be really the _web site author_. But I disagree on that one :).

Answer (score 1):

The word author in this context is ambiguous. The author of a web page might be either the author of the html/xml (as stated here http://www.webmarketingnow.com/tips/meta-tags-meta-author.html) or as you claim, it may be the author of the text content of the page.

There is also the web_author tag, to distinguish these two: http://www.metatags.info/meta_name_webauthor

This kind of ambiguity is common these days, in the world of IT, because the complexity of the situation was not considered beforehand. In general when using tags and references we need to be as specific to the context as we can.

Moreover, an analogy to the paper world would not be entirely correct. The paper world is not as complex as a web page. A web page may have an html/xml developer, a javascript developer, a flash developer, a css developer, a designer, a server side developer, and a host (which would be more like publisher).

I agree with you that the list of meta tags are not complete, but the purpose of meta tags is not very clear anyway. It seems that these days people use them for other indexing services than SEO (http://webdesign.about.com/od/metatagsbasics/f/why-use-meta-tags.htm). Since there indexing services are arbitrary, the actual use of this content is also arbitrary. In other words there is no way to say whether an indexing service will look for html/xml authors or text authors.

Thus, my answer is to be as specific as you can and need in the context. If there is only one person writing both html/xml and text content, that person can be referred to as author. However, since in your case you find the text content author to be the "author", you can add the web developer as "web_author". You may also use "web_application_developer", and promote this use. Of course, I think it's good also to use humans.txt.

After all, the web is being constantly developed, and we as humans are improving it for the future. The more we discuss and promote more precise and practical technology, the better the web will be. Even if one standard wouldn't survive, it may still have an impact for an even better solution for the future.